# Family member of an EEA citizen

Tags: visas

I am British and my husband has a permanent resident permit stamp in his Indian passport. How can we get the family member of EEA member stamp on his passport? Where should he apply?

Comment: Why do you want the "family member of EEA member stamp"?

Answer (score 2):

I make the following assumptions.  If any is incorrect, please advise.

- You and your husband live together in the UK.
- the "permanent resident permit stamp" is a stamp that says either "indefinite leave to enter the UK" or "indefinite leave to remain in the UK"
- you are asking whether your husband can get an [EEA family permit](https://www.gov.uk/family-permit).
- you are asking about this because you want to travel together to another EU or Schengen country.

The answer is no, your husband cannot get one, but he also has no use for one.  The EEA family permit is valid only in the United Kingdom.  Your husband already has indefinite leave to enter or remain, so the EEA family permit provides him with no benefit.

If you are asking because you want to travel to the Schengen area, then your husband will need to apply for a Schengen visa.  The application must be submitted to the representation of the country that will be your "main destination."

If your husband will be traveling with you, or traveling to join you, he should apply for the visa as the family member of an EU citizen, including a copy of your passport to support that claim.  In that case, the application will be free of charge, should be processed expeditiously, and will be judged according to far less restrictive criteria.

If you are asking because you want to travel to any other EU country that is not in the Schengen area, your husband will need to apply for a visa from the country in question.  The more favorable conditions of the visa application process also apply in this case.

If you are asking because you want to *move* to another country, the question is off topic here; instead, you can ask at [Expatriates](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com).